# cleaning a project and regeneratig class files in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

After I clean a project in eclipse I don't see the class files generated in the output folder "bin" although there's no build error, what can I do to make it regenerate the class files?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

It might be that your project is configured to write classes to somewhere other than ./bin

Comment: at first it was configured to do so, but I changed the classpath to include bin.

Comment: Huh? The classpath has got nothing to do with where the classes are written (at least not explicitly - the project will automatically include its "output directory" on its classpath). If you've explicitly added bin to your classpath, this might be what is confusing it?

Comment: when you create a project in eclipse a .classpath file is generated. it includes the source and output paths, and yes I added it manually.

Comment: I know; I'm an Eclipse user. Having to futz with that file manual sounds fishy to me. I've been using Eclipse since 1.0 and have probably hand-edited that file, like, twice in that time. See if re-creating the project helps. (i.e. backup your .project and .classpath, remove the project from Eclipse, delete the .project and .classpath files from disk, and re-import the project into Eclipse)

Comment: Yeah at the end that was what I did, wasn't worth spending all the time figuring out what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Under the "Project" menu, see if the option "Build Automatically" is checked.

**Edit**: Have you checked this on Eclipse or on a file browser? Sometimes Eclipse takes a long time to refresh changes in the file system. Force a refresh by right clicking the bin folder and clicking on "Refresh" on the contextual menu.

**Edit**: Check your build path, try reconfiguring it from scratch, I don't know if this can help, but who knows...

Comment: yes it is, I tried unchecking and checking again, but still nothing.

Comment: That's odd, there might be something wrong with your Eclipse installation. What JRE are you using?

Comment: I downloaded Java SE development Kit 6, which had JRE bundled with it I think.

Answer (score 0):

To generate these .class files manually, which are lost after cleaning the project, uncheck build automically which is under Project and then right click on your project and select build project which will regenerate your lost .class files